# Google Drive Api Application Data Folder listChildren returns empty buffer

Tags: android, google-drive-api

Good day!

I am using google drive api in my application. I am trying to store some application information in files in the `application data folder` on google drive and then, when needed modify it inside these files.

Files are successfully created and data is written there also successfully.

However, when I try to modify data, I request children of the `appDataFolder` and the result I get is empty `MetadataBuffer`. I have tried to use filters, or without them. Same result both for `listChildren(...)` and `queryChildren(...)`.

Didn't find any solution also. Here some code:

```
Drive.DriveApi.getAppFolder(mGoogleApiClient).listChildren(mGoogleApiClient)
        .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult>()
{
    @Override
    public void onResult(DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult result)
    {
        if(!result.getStatus().isSuccess())
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "query children fail");
            return;
        }

        MetadataBuffer mdb = result.getMetadataBuffer();
        Log.i(TAG, "mdb count = " + mdb.getCount());    //Here i get "mdb count = 0".

        //...

    }
}
```

Using `Drive.SCOPE_FILE` and `Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER`.

I appreciate any help! Thank You in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Awww, very stupid mistake. I have created files with `getRootFolder` instead of `getAppFolder`.